# videos are not able to index after uploading successfully

Tags: azure-video-indexer

After indexing 65%, error "There was a problem indexing this video, please delete or re-index this media" is coming. I tried with .mp4 and .mkv files. Also, I tried videos downloaded from different website. Any ideas?? Can anyone help me?

```
ID: Trial---1b08a076c6---b2e118d2-36f3-4a41-8a5b-0b4a62ccb7a0---job-1b08a076c6-VIJob-fb96e-r1
Trial---9ccae63242---28c608e6-aafa-41a0-b89d-35194b997ec9---job-9ccae63242-VIJob-ff697-r1
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reaching out, I am investigating the issue with another team but it might have been a transient issue, please try again and update if the issue reproduces.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes same error is reproducing. I tried near about 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

We found a problem potentially related to what you are experiencing and working on a fix we will update as soon as fix is shipped so you would be able to try again